# repeating a foreign key in a column

Tags: mysql

hi i have this database table where i have for example

```
-transaction number- pk
-id_number- fk from employees table
-request- 
-department_request_status-
-department_oic- fk from id_number of employees table again
-headoffice
-headoffice_oic- fk from id_number of employees table again
```

can i for example left join them then show the names of the three id owners in the table?

for example

```
SELECT 
            table.ID_NUM,
            table.DEP_OIC,
            table.HeadOffc_OIC
            employees.LNAME, ===>select this for ID_NUM,DEP_OIC, and HeadOffc_OIC
            employees.FNAME  ===>select this for ID_NUM,DEP_OIC, and HeadOffc_OIC
        FROM leave_application
        LEFT JOIN employees
        WHERE leave_application.ID_NUM = employees.ID_NUM
        LEFT JOIN employees
        WHERE leave_application.DEP_OIC = employees.ID_NUM
```

how can i do it properly? is it possible? or i have to break them into three tables??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can join each EmployeeID (id_number,department_oic,headoffice_oic) with leave_application Table separately and see each of them as a table, then left join all result with leave_application, now you have all three owners name in single row:

```
    select leave_application.tranid, HeadOffFName, HeadOffLName, DepFName, DepLName, FName, LName from leave_application 
LEFT JOIN
    (select TranID, FName as HeadOffFName, LName as HeadOffLName from 
    Employee inner join leave_application
    on Employee.EmpID = leave_application.HeadOffc_OIC)Head
    ON leave_application.TranID = Head.tranid
left join
    (select TranID, FName as DepFName, LName as DepLName from 
    Employee inner join leave_application
    on Employee.EmpID = leave_application.DEP_OIC)Dep
ON leave_application.TranID = Dep.tranid
left join
    (select TranID, FName, LName from 
    Employee inner join leave_application
    on Employee.EmpID = leave_application.ID_NUM)Office
ON leave_application.TranID = Office.tranid
```

Comment: what does this line mean `select leave_application.tranid, HeadOffFName, HeadOffLName, DepFName, DepLName, FName, LName from leave_application` ?

Comment: HeadoffFname is headoffice_oic owner first name
from query result in Head

Comment: please search the HeadOffFName and other fields in answer, you will see where they are generated.

Comment: so TRAN is the table? then tranid, HeadOffFName, HeadOffLName, DepFName etc will be nicknames of the columns? am i right?

Comment: i have changed [Tran] to leave_application in edited answer,
yes they are the nicknames of Employees

Comment: wait buddy, i have to ask you on this part `LEFT JOIN
    (select TranID, FName as HeadOffFName, LName as HeadOffLName from ` i wont do for example `tablename.TranID` ??

Comment: no because there is only one TranID inside Parentheses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107203/discussion-between-kev-m-and-saeed-taran).